# what happens to the files fetched when a git fetch command is interrupted

Tags: git

I am learning how to use git and i am wondering what becomes of the files fetched before a git fetch command is interrupted by power failure or connectivity problems.Will the files fetched before the interruption be copied to my computer?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `git fetch` will transfer objects from the remote repository. To maintain Git’s integrity, only complete objects are ever written to the local repository. So if a fetch is interrupted, you will end up with parts of the objects, meaning the fetch wasn’t completed, but no single object will be corrupt. On a subsequent fetch, Git will then again calculate which objects are missing and get those.

Comment: This implies that objects transferred before the interruption will not be transferred again. That is not the case.

Comment: That’s the case when individual Git objects are transferred. See also my comment to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

When git fetch starts receiving objects it creates a temporary file in the
`objects/pack` directory of the repository to hold the new objects. Only once
the fetch is complete will that temporary file be renamed to a name that will
be honored by other git processes. If the fetch is interrupted that temporary
file will mostly be ignored, including by another fetch; so anything that was
transferred before the interruption will be transferred again.

In time (2 weeks by default) the temporary pack file will be eligible for
removal by the garbage collection process. You can force that to be done right
away by running `git gc --prune=now`.

Comment: This is only true when a fetch fetches pack objects. Not every fetch does that though. When normal Git objects are fetched, these are directly moved to the correct folder.

Comment: @poke In my testing, even if I do a fetch of objects that are loose on the server they are transferred and received as a pack. Although that would obviously be different if working with a dumb server.

Comment: I tested it myself by fetching and interrupting it immediately with Ctrl+C. Only some normal Git object files were created, no pack file. If a pack file is used probably depends on the amount of data transferred.

Comment: @poke That's probably the case then. But, transfers which contain enough data would take longer, and thus be more likely to be interrupted. Also, in that case needing to receive that data again would be a bigger issue.